# how to setuid on a file, that is owned by some other user

Tags: unix

How can I set setuid for a file, that is owned by some other user ?

I tried, setting the profile and changing the USER variable, but doesn't help .

Comment: What do you mean by setting the profile?

Answer (score 3):

Users can only set the setuid bit on their own files, or root can set them on any file. This is a security feature - if you could set the setuid bit on someone else's file, you could run it to become that user.

It determines who you are based on your actual login ID (you can see this with the `id` command), not the USER variable or whatever you mean by "setting the profile".